# Celery & RabbitMQ configuration

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I use Celery and RabbintMQ for my project.

I have 3 servers (Main, A, B). A and B are calculating the tasks from Main server, then they post response to him.

This is an organizational question: where I need to install Celery and RabbitMQ?

As I think, RabbitMQ must be install on Main server (create rabbitmq user, etc.), Celery - on A and B servers. Or A and B also needs to install RabbitMQ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to install RabbitMQ on all servers. Installing it in one server is sufficient. You just need to route tasks to A & B servers.

Also, remember AMQP is network protocol, the producers, consumers and the broker can all reside on same or different machines. Following are the possible arrangements for them.

[image]

**Producer:** A producer is a user application that sends messages.

**Broker:** A broker receives massages from producer and router them to consumer. A broker consists an exchange and one or more queues.

**Consumer:** A consumer is an application that receives messages and process them.

Comment: so, rabbitmq on main server and celery on another (A and B)?